# IQKeyboardManager has no member sharedManager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iqkeyboardmanager

i am using IQKeyboardManager pod, for my swift 4.0 project.

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

after pod update, the above code is not working.

Comment: please check https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager 

and make sure add this line `IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an answer to your question: [Type 'IQKeyboardManager' has no member 'sharedManager'](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/1297) by [hackiftekhar](https://github.com/hackiftekhar)

Since IQKeyboardManagerSwift version 6.0.0, `sharedManager()` has been replaced with `shared`

For **pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'** or **pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '6.0.0'**, try this:

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
```

Look at this: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/blob/master/IQKeyboardManagerSwift/IQKeyboardManager.swift

[image]

---

[Swift Demo code by IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/blob/master/Demo/Swift_Demo/AppDelegate.swift)

[image]

---

For **pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '5.0.0'**, try this

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code.it's perfectly working in swift4.
install pod file .

> pod 'IQKeyboardManager'

import IQKeyboardManager in AppDelegate

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = true

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It Works Perfect

Uncheck the Allow App Extensions API only for IQKeyboardManager Pod.

To get it Click on Pod -> IQkeyboardManager
See Image below

[image]